# MEF Add module twice to catalog

Tags: module, mef, catalog

Do you know how to add the same module twice to a catalog with different parameters?

```
ITest acc1 = new smalltest("a", 0)
ITest acc2 = new smalltest("b", 1)

AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(??)
AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(??)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As MEF is limited to its usage of attributes and can be configured by using the Import and Export attributes unlike the flexibility usually provided by IoC Containers, just how one may extend a `Part` in MEF, one may extend it from a referenced DLL, you could also do something similar where a class inherits from a previous MEF Part by creating a class which exposes some properties with the `[ExportAttribute]`. The attribute is not limited to the usage on a class, but can be applied to properties. For example, how about something like this.

```cs
public class PartsToExport
{
    [Export(typeof(ITest))]
    public Implementation A
    {
        get { return new Implementation("A", 5); }
    }

    [Export(typeof(ITest))]
    public Implementation B
    {
        get { return new Implementation("B", 10); }
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    void WhoAmI(Action<string, int> action);
}

[Export]
public class Implementation : ITest
{
    private string _method;
    private readonly int _value;

    public Implementation(string method, int value)
    {
        _method = method;
        _value = value;
    }

    public void WhoAmI(Action<string, int> action)
    {
        action(_method, _value);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        var tests = container.GetExportedValues<ITest>();

        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            test.WhoAmI((s, i) => Console.WriteLine("I am {0} with a value of {1}.", s, i));
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs the following to the console:

I am A with a value of 5.
I am B with a value of 10.